# Embedding an external form in a page

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a service that uses the following embed script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">app_id="XXX";distribution_key="dist_2";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://loader.knack.com/XXX/dist_2/knack.js"></script>
<div id="knack-dist_2">Loading...</div>
```

Putting this in using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` works, but only on full refresh.  If I click a link to this page, it doesn't load.

Are there any tricks to get this to load?